# Getting the color from a beamer theme?

Tags: beamer, color

How do I find out what color a beamer theme uses? In particular, what is the color that the Singapore theme uses? I'd like to grab this color so that I can color my tables with it and remain consistent with the general theme. I've copied and pasted the `.sty` file for Singapore below. I really wasn't able to glean much from looking at it.

```
% Copyright 2007 by Till Tantau
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%
% See the file doc/licenses/LICENSE for more details.

\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header: /cvsroot/latex-beamer/latex-beamer/themes/theme/beamerthemeSingapore.sty,v 1.10 2007/01/28 20:48:30 tantau Exp $


\DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer


\mode<presentation>

\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{use=structure,bg=structure.fg!25!bg}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}


\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\AtBeginDocument{%
  {
    \usebeamercolor{section in head/foot}
  }

  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@headfade}{\paperwidth}
  {%
    color(0cm)=(bg);
    color(1.25cm)=(section in head/foot.bg)%
  }

  \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=}
}

\addtoheadtemplate{\pgfuseshading{beamer@headfade}\vskip-1.25cm}{}

\beamertemplatedotitem

\mode
<all>
```

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear: are you using this theme in your presentation?  Thus if you had a method whereby TeX could figure out the colour within the document, but you never knew the exact RGB values, would that suffice for your purposes?

Comment: Yes, that would suffice. Probably be ideal actually.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A beamer presentation uses several colors. beamer provides commands for using colors of the presentation elements. Choose the element of which you would like to use the color and apply it, for example:

```
{\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure} text}
```

prints text in a blue color, with Singapore theme.

Here `fg` means foreground, `bg` means background, instead of `structure` you may use `title in head`, `section in head`, `normal text` and many more. Have a look into the [beamer manual](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) for learning more about using colors.

Comment: Specifically, Section 17.2 "Changing the Colors ...".  The `\usebeamercolor` command, and all its variants, are explained in Section 17.2.2.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I checked out the manual and should mention that `structure.fg` was particularly useful to me. Because I'm coloring rows I need to do something like `\rowcolor{<my color>}`. `structure.fg` worked for `<my color>` whereas `\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure}` did not. Is this regular practice?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewStacey, that manual is ridiculously difficult to find things in.

Comment: Where can I find the information related to the use of `title in head`?

Comment: The manual notes that you can use this command without the optional argument `fg` or `bg`, so only `\usebeamercolor{title in head}` for example. This sets the color names `fg` and `bg` to the foreground and background colors of that structure. This is very useful because you can use the color names in other commands that expect a color, such as `\sethlcolor` from `soul` (as `\sethlcolor{bg}` for example), whereas `\sethlcolor{structure.bg}` does not always seem to work as expected.

Comment: @Marijn, maybe related to my comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33764/getting-the-color-from-a-beamer-theme#comment1417533_53604 ?

Answer (score 9):

All the informations on color themes are in the directory `Beamer\Base\Themes`.
But it's easier to write `color=block body.bg` to use the background color of the body of block, independently of the theme chosen.

Comment: Notice that you need to have *used* the color before to be able to use, for example, `\rowcolor{block body.bg}`. I suggest sticking a (null) `{\usebeamercolor[bg]{block body}}%` at the start of the frame to stay on the safe side.