# Second section/title in middle of beamer frame?

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I want to have a second section within a single beamer frame, to visually separate two concepts. Basically I want the frame to be two half-height frames (excluding the bits within the header/footer).

In a normal book/article document, I'd be able to use `\section{}` and this would actually print the section name. This doesn't work in Beamer - sections don't appear in the text.

I would like to have the same formatting as the frame title (or sub-title) for the second section/title (i.e. use the formatting from the beamer theme in use). I would also like the section to show up in the TOC.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: I ended up using the `block` environment, with some custom colours. It'd be nice to have the colours automatically come from the theme though (the default block style in the theme I'm using is crap). An answer describing how to use the title colours to style the block environment would be acceptable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so following the answer in [Getting the color from a beamer theme?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33764/getting-the-color-from-a-beamer-theme), I figured out a solution:

In the preamble:

```
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{use={frametitle},fg=frametitle.fg,bg=frametitle.bg}
```

Which copies the frametitle colours to the block title.

Then in text:

```
\begin{block}{Section title here}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item some stuff
  \end{itemize}
\end{block}
```