# How to modify the following Beamer theme?

Tags: beamer

I'm using

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{BeamerColor}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{myown}
\usecolortheme[named=salmon]{structure}
\setbeamercovered{transparent} }

\setbeamercolor{lower separation line head}{bg=LightSteelBlue3}
\setbeamercolor{lineup}{bg=salmon}
\setbeamercolor{linemid}{bg=IndianRed2}
\setbeamercolor{linebottom}{bg=LightSteelBlue3}

\begin{document}
title
\end{document}
```

where     `\usetheme{myown}` is defines as

```
\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}


\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.137,0.466,0.741}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black} \setbeamercolor{item}{fg=black}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.7ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
    \vskip2pt\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.7ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
} \mode <all>

\makeatletter
\DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\mode<presentation>

% The footline template is a modification of the one used in the
% Torino theme, Copyright 2007 by Marco Barisione
\setbeamercolor*{lineup}{parent=palette primary}
\setbeamercolor*{linemid}{parent=palette secondary}
\setbeamercolor*{linebottom}{parent=palette tertiary}
\setbeamercolor*{page header}{parent=titlelike}
\mode <all>

% some lengths (the height of the lines)
\newlength{\beamer@decolines@linemid}
\setlength{\beamer@decolines@linemid}{.015\paperheight}

\newlength{\beamer@decolines@lineup}
\setlength{\beamer@decolines@lineup}{.025\paperheight}

\newlength{\beamer@decolines@linebottom}
\setlength{\beamer@decolines@linebottom}{.01\paperheight}


% String used between the current page and the total page count.
\def\beamer@decolines@pageofpages{/}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{decolines theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  % First line.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.8\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@lineup,dp=0pt]{lineup}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@lineup,dp=0pt,right]{}%
    \hbox{\usebeamerfont{palette primary}\footnotesize\insertframenumber{} \beamer@decolines@pageofpages{} \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  } %
  % Second line.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@linemid,dp=0pt]{linemid}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  } %
  % Third line.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.9\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@linebottom,dp=0pt]{linebottom}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@linebottom,dp=0pt]{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

and the question is how to modify the theme to get the two top lines in the same color as is used down, that is the first one salmon and the second one IndianRed2.

Comment: I think this might help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33764/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the two colors (I assume that the color names used are available in your system):

```
\setbeamercolor{top}{bg=salmon}
\setbeamercolor{bottom}{bg=IndianRed2}%
```

and then change the definition og the headline template to

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.7ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{top}
    \vskip2pt\insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \ifbeamer@theme@subsection%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1.7ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{bottom}
      \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line head}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

Comment: @Gonzola: great, exactly what I wanted. Just a little change if it is possible to change color of letters on top, instead of white, black. I tried to write \setbeamercolor{top}{bg=salmon}
\setbeamercolor{bottom}{fg=black,bg=IndianRed2}, but it does not work

Comment: @Laura You need to redefine the appropriate template(s); for example, for the color of the section names in the headline you can use something like `\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black}`.

Comment: @Gonzola: It's prefect now. To one of my old questions. Could you have a look at tex.stackexchange.com/a/27302/86 and the line that I wanted to take away is there as well. It is situated on the bottom of the page on the right side. Just up the title September in the yellow part. That's what I want to remove. Is it possible?

Comment: @Laura the problem is that I don't see any line there! The only line I see above September in the yellow part is a line belonging to the grid (drawn manually by Andrew), not to the `beamer` theme. Do you perhaps want to discuss this in a chat room? Comments are not the best place to place code.