# How do I reference a template colour in beamer?

Tags: beamer, color

Say I want to draw a `beamercolorbox` and have it be coloured with the colour used for `block body alerted.bg`. How can I do this? I read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33764/31250), but it turned out to be unhelpful. I need to somehow reference the colour by name. So I'd like something like this

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\paperwidth]{block body.fg}
   <content>
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

But that does not work. Judging from fruitless googling there seems to be no easy way to directly use the template-defined colour to stay consistent, is there?

Comment: Please make your code compilable with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to invert a colour?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{invert block body alerted}{fg=block body alerted.bg, bg=block body alerted.fg}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}

\begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\paperwidth]{block body alerted}
    blub
\end{beamercolorbox}

\begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\paperwidth]{invert block body alerted}
    blub
\end{beamercolorbox}        

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, I do not. The question is merely how to reference template-defined colours by name for use in arbitrary places. But `\begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\paperwidth]{block body alerted}...` does what I want, somehow I did not realise this actually works.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realise you can just call them by their names, i.e.

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\paperwidth]{block body}
   <content>
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

but apparently, you cannot reference background or foreground colours like this.

Comment: You can reference background and foreground colours like this, just `beamercolorbox` expects a full beamer colour as argument, consisting of a foreground and a background colour.