# Retrieve frametitle-fg-color in beamer

Tags: beamer, color

Could you please help me on how to "retrieve" the color a beamer document currently uses for coloring headline fonts?

I would like to use it to color ordinary text, as in

```
\textcolor{\beamerheadlinefgcolor}{Some text.}
```

Comment: There is `\usebeamercolor[fg]{beamer color name}`.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33774. The corresponding beamer color template used in headlines is `headline`. Do distinguish `headline` (normally containing section titles as links) from `frametitle` (the `<title>` in `\begin{frame}{<title>}`).

Comment: Thank you very much and my apologies for not having found the related post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\structure{some text}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
    Hello \structure{World}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```