# How to use a Beamer Color as any other Named Color?

Tags: beamer, color

How can I use a Beamer Color, lets say the one given by `\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette primary}` as color name in order to be used in a `\rowcolors` command for example.

In the following MWE I would like to use something like `beamercolor[bg]{palette primary}` instead of `lightgray` in `\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}`:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}

\begin{tabular}{r|rrrrr}
  \hline
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
  \hline
1 & 2.36 & 1.08 & -0.49 & -0.82 & -0.65 \\
  2 & -0.68 & -1.13 & -0.42 & -0.72 & 1.51 \\
  3 & -1.00 & 0.02 & -0.54 & 0.31 & 1.28 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comments at [Getting the color from a beamer theme?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33764/getting-the-color-from-a-beamer-theme) you can use the Beamer color names in the same way as a regular color name if you first 'activate' them using `\usebeamercolor`. You can put this inside of a `{}` group so that the `\usebeamercolor` statement does not actually apply the color anywhere but it still makes the color name available for commands outside of the `{}` group.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}

{\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette primary}}
\rowcolors{1}{}{palette primary.bg}

\begin{tabular}{r|rrrrr}
  \hline
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
  \hline
1 & 2.36 & 1.08 & -0.49 & -0.82 & -0.65 \\
  2 & -0.68 & -1.13 & -0.42 & -0.72 & 1.51 \\
  3 & -1.00 & 0.02 & -0.54 & 0.31 & 1.28 \\
   \hline
\end{tabular}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that I added a frame title to the MWE, otherwise LaTeX thought that `{\usebeamercolor[bg]{palette primary}}` was the frame title, which does not make the color available - it needs to be inside of the frame.

Comment: That's just perfect! Thanks a lot! Just a comment, it seems that the "*activation*" with the `\usebeamercolor[..]{..}` command can be done in preambule (before the `\begin{document}` and so no need to put it between brackets `{}`. Thanks again !